# Probability problem about polynomial

Tags: probability

Let $\xi$ and $\eta$ be independent random variable and their expected value and variances are $m_{\xi}, \sigma_{\xi}^2$ and $m_{\eta}, \sigma_{\eta}^2$ respectively. Consider a random polynomial $t^2+\xi t + \eta$. Let $t_1$ and $t_2$ be this polynomial roots.
I need to find the expected value of coefficients of random polynomial with roots $t_1^2, t_2^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If polynomial has roots $t_1^2, t_2^2$, it must be like:

$$(x - t_1^2)(x- t_2^2) = x^2 - x(t_1^2 + t_2^2) + t_1^2t_2^2 $$

so coefficients will be:

$$a = -(t_1^2 + t_2^2)$$ and $$b = t_1^2t_2^2$$

Now we can find expected value of $a$ and $b$. From Vieta's formulas:

$$t_1 + t_2 = -\xi$$ and
$$t_1t_2 = \eta$$

Hence:

$$b=\eta^2$$ and
$$a=-((t_1+t_2)^2 - 2t_1t_2) = -(\xi^2 - 2\eta) = 2\eta - \xi^2$$

Now we can find expected value:

$$\mathbb{E}a = 2m_{\eta} - \sigma_{\xi}^2 - m_{\xi}^2$$

$$\mathbb{E}b = \sigma_{\eta}^2 + m_{\eta}^2$$